# Use case for typedef

Tags: c++, frameworks, typedef

In the robotic framework ROS (www.ros.org) there are some clases defining its member variables using typedef and I really don't find a reason for this. For instance:

```
class Point : public ros::Msg
{
    public:
      typedef double _x_type;
      _x_type x;
      typedef double _y_type;
      _y_type y;
      typedef double _z_type;
      _z_type z;

    Point():
      x(0),
      y(0),
      z(0)
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone has any clue about this? What's the reason for defining the class Point like that and not simply like this:

```
class Point : public ros::Msg
{
    public:
      double x;
      double y;
      double z;

    Point():
      x(0),
      y(0),
      z(0)
    {
    }
}
```

The whole implementation of this class can be found here:

https://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/geometry_msgs/html/Point_8h_source.html

Comment: There used to be a time when you couldn't deduced types and must rely on names

Comment: Note there is also a `Point32` type which has the same typedefs, except they are `float`.

Comment: Did you read those sources by yourself? They use `double` indeed

Comment: My guess is that it allows the identification of the axis by type.  This might allow simplification of certain geometric calculations.

Comment: Most probably some macro used that needs to determine member type by its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of doing this sort of thing is maintainability.

If one day they decide that double just isn't ok, but what's really needed is `super_extra_accurate_double` which may or may not be a class, it's trivial to change and if people have avoided making the assumption that it's a double (for example by doing `memcpy(sizeof(double))` rather than `memcpy(sizeof(Point::_x_type))` (sure, memcpy is a bad example, but it'll do for this answer); then they can change the type and no code will need to be re-written to handle the new size.

Answer (score 0):

It is so you can easily write generic (templated) code that can operate on more than one `Point` type. As long as the `Point` type has these typedefs you can easily declare variables with the same type as the corresponding member variable.

ROS has a number of point-like types `Point`, `Point32`, `Vector3`, `Quaternion`, etc that all have these typedefs, some are double, some are float. Let's say we want to make a templated `Triangle` class that can use any point-like type:

```
template<typename T>
class Triangle {
    public:
      T vertex_1;
      T vertex_2;
      T vertex_3;
};
```

Now let's say you want to write a member function that returns the height of the triangle. Remember that ROS predates things like `auto`,  `decltype` or `using` aliases but you can use the typdefs:

```
typename T::_z_type height() const {
  typename T::_z_type min_z = std::min(std::min(vertex_1.z, vertex_2.z), vertex_3.z);
  typename T::_z_type max_z = std::max(std::min(vertex_1.z, vertex_2.z), vertex_3.z);
  return max_z - min_z;
}
```

Comment: Can you develop? templated code using T.x and T.y should do the job even without the typedef

Comment: @sandwood With the typedef you can use the *type* `ClassName::_x_type` in a template regardless of what it is. ROS is older than `decltype`.

Comment: @sandwood I've added a (slightly contrived) example.

Answer (score -3):

It can help the developper to avoid mistake in their logics, later.

To help them to not do any math operations on x or y together.

Also the function can be written as expecting explicitly x or y data.

Comment: Typedef would not stop you to do math operations.

Comment: @Slava if you mean that the compiler will not complain if you do a mistake, I agree.

Comment: Then how that `typedef` helps you not to do math operations on them?

Comment: When you are debugging legacy code and you run into this code:

_x_type a=5;
_y_type b=5;

res = a * b; will be accepted by the compiler. But as you have defined different typedef, you know that you are doing something functionnally wrong.

Comment: Also I do not understand how that would help to avoid mistake or write function.